# Flutter doesn't update launcher icon

Tags: android, flutter, icons, launcher

I created a new icon for my app and I used flutter launcher icons for generate the launcher icon.
In the midmap folders there is the ic_launcher.png and if I open it is my new launcher icon.
But if I install the app via android studio on my phone it shows the old icon.

It happened to me even when I created the first icon.
It went all well but the app had the default flutter icon.
It started to show the new one when I changed the app name but now I cannot change it again.

I already tried with the flutter-launcher-icons widget, to use flutter clean, ecc... but it doesn't change.
Why there is this problem? And where the app takes the old logo information?

---

***UPDATE***

I discovered a workaround for this problem.
If I delete all generated files (even the ones that looks right) and then I regenerate them when I install the app on the phone the icon looks right.

Answer (score 1):

There will be 5 different mipmap files within android/app/src/res/main folder. Each mipmap consists icon launcher of different dimensions and pixels. Make sure you have replaced all 5 icon launchers with your generated Icon Launcher.

You can Generate Icon Launcher from [here](https://appicon.co/).

Comment: I updated all the images, I even tried with the generator that you linked. If i open the files in the mipmap folders in Android Studio I see the new icon but if I install it in the phone I see the old one

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the app from device and re-installing again ? Also try flutter clean command and then flutter pub get before re-installing

Comment: Tried both but they didn't work. Tried uninstalling, clean, get and reinstall bot the debug and the release version but nothing solves

Comment: Please attach screenshots of what you have done and also of the error  you got in console

Comment: I don't have errors, it simply load the old icon instead of the new one

Comment: Have you replaced the entire mipmap folders or just the icon which you have generated ?

Comment: Tried both. I replaced only the icon inside every folder and it didn't work so I replaced every folder with the ones that I took from appicon.co but didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I see this issue still hasn't been resolved. I did find a workaround when I ran into the same problem. Just add

```
adaptive_icon_foreground: 'assets\logo.png'
adaptive_icon_background: '#000000'
```

in your ***pubspec.yaml*** under ***flutter_icons:*** where you can mention any suitable background color in hex for *adaptive_icon_background*.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, where the app icon would always be the androids default one. The way I fixed this, was by looking at the following **Github thread:** https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59305

I noticed, that there was an error in my AndroidManifest.xml, where the android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon" was not inside the application-tag. After placing the ">" after android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon", it worked for me.

How it looked:

[Not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt5a9.png)

How it should look:

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyEJ4.png)

I hope this helped

Comment: Unfortunately the androidManifest.xml is already well formatted